# Javascript not running on my website

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I am trying to make a simple dropdown menu with HTML/CSS/JS.
In fiddle this is working just fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/SLGdE/984/

But, If I try the same code on my website it doesn't work. Do I have to activate JS or something? I'm lost. I've tried moving the JS in the head-section, body-section and now I have it externally.

Here is how I have it on my site:

test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
<title></title>
<script src="menu.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h4 id="menu1"></h4>
<ul>Menu1
<li class="submenu1">Status</li>
<li class="submenu1">Submenu 2</li>
<li class="submenu1">Submenu 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="menu2"><h4>Menu2</h4>
<li class="submenu2">Submenu 1</li>
<li class="submenu2">Submenu 2</li>
<li class="submenu2">Submenu 3</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

menu.js

```
$(function() {
$('#menu1').click(function(){
$('.submenu1').slideToggle();
});
});

$(function() {
$('#menu2').click(function(){
$('.submenu2').slideToggle();
});
});
```

style2.css

```
.submenu1{display:none;}
.submenu2{display:none;}
```

Comment: Do you have JQuery installed?

Comment: You didn't include jQuery...

Comment: Also you only need one `$(function(){...}` or `document.ready`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you do not have the JQuery Library installed, which is required for the  coding in `menu.js`.
[You can download it from JQuery.com](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: awesome, that was the problem. Thank you very much!  I normally never use JS.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

before your menu.js script

It will add jQuery to your website.

Also, if You are new to JS & other webdev stuff, the best place to examine your JS script is console (for example from firebug https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/firebug/) or native chrome webdeveloper tools. It will show You most of errors (like this from your example)